# VLC for Windows won't play MP4A audio on live stream

Tags: vlc-media-player, codec, audio-streaming

I'm attempting to play back a live H.264 feed in VLC for Windows (latest version). The feed comes from a HDMI to IPTV encoder. In OBS, the feed plays fine, and streams to youtube etc, audio and video work perfectly. However, when I attempt to play the stream in VLC, the video plays but there is no audio. In codec info, it shows the audio as MP4A, but in the statistics, it shows 0 bytes decoded. I have tried all the Audio Output options in VLC, but not getting any sound. Debug logs show the 'faad' audio decoder is being used, but there are no errors being raised regarding audio decoding.

Any ideas? Thanks